# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to long

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, I sought a little but i can't figure why it's append ...

If someone could help me.

```
public class Menu extends Activity
{
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private GridView grid;
private Button add;
private Button info;
private Button deco;

private String lab[];
private String id[];

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_account);
    info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);
    deco = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deconnexion);

    add.setOnClickListener(add_listener);
    info.setOnClickListener(info_listener);
    deco.setOnClickListener(deco_listener);

    try
    {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("TMP_TTTT_TLA", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "Impossible d'avoir accès à la base de donnéee.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT a_id, a_name FROM Account", null);

    lab = new String[c.getCount()];
    id = new String[c.getCount()];
    int i = 0;

    if (c.getCount() != 0 )
    {
        if  (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                lab[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("a_name"));
                id[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("a_id"));
                i++;
            }
            while(c.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    c.close();

    grid.setAdapter(new Adapter_Menu(this, lab));
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Intent x = new Intent(Menu.this, Account_View.class);
            x.putExtra("Id", id[position]);
            startActivity(x);
        }
    });
}
}
```

The problem come from this line :

```
x.putExtra("Id", id[position]);
```

It's say The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to long.

Help me please.

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace with the exception message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have two variables called id:

```
private String id[];
```

and

```
long id
```

of `onItemClick`.

Just change your `onItemClickListener` to the following:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long anid) 
    {
        Intent x = new Intent(Menu.this, Account_View.class);
        x.putExtra("Id", id[position]);
        startActivity(x);
    }
```

Please note the name of your the last argument of `onItemClick`.

Comment: +1 When a class field and a parameter have the same name, the parameter takes precedence in the context of the method. That's why the _"not so nifty"_ alternative is to use `this.id` to refer to the array and `id` to refer to the long.

Comment: Wahou ... Really don't think at this ... Thank you so much and excuse me for my distraction